How to count resolved comments only via VBA in Excel
By using the Comments property of a worksheet it is possible to retrieve the number of comments in said worksheet by accessing its Count property in turn: Worksheets(1).Comments.Count.
The Comment object is a member of the Comments collection containing the following properties: Application, Author, Creator, Parent, Shape and Visible.
Given this information I was only able to retrieve the number of comments per worksheet but would also like to see the amount and/or ratio of resolved to open comments. Am I missing some hack to utilize the provided properties (maybe like Visible) to somehow get information of whether the comment was marked as resolved?
It is not possible to delete the resolved comments since they are used as some sort of documentation of the decisions and changes.


Only threaded comment has the resolved status. Normal comment (Insert by Review > Notes > New Note) doesn't have the status.


In M365, the terms comments and notes can be a bit confusing.

The Comments group actually works with threaded comments object.
The Notes drop-down menu works with comments object.


Microsoft documentation:

CommentThreaded object (Excel)

Sub CountCmt()
    Dim ct As CommentThreaded, iCnt As Long, iTotal As Long
    iTotal = ActiveSheet.CommentsThreaded.Count
    If iTotal = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No comments"
    Else
        For Each ct In ActiveSheet.CommentsThreaded
            If ct.Resolved Then iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Next
        MsgBox "Resolved comments: " & iCnt & vbCr & _
            "Total comments: " & iTotal
    End If
End Sub


Thanks for the clarification, I came accross the CommentsThreaded but somehow interpreted it as a special collection containing only the comments with replies. The Resolved property is not listed in the documentation, how do you get all properties available?

@Jan_B If you type in, for example, Dim ws As Worksheet: ws.CommentsThreaded(1)., then IntelliSense should open up a list of all the Properties and Methods that VBA is currently willing to admit to…

In VBE press F2 to open Object Browser, search commentthreaded, select the object in Search Results, you will see all properties and methods. https://i.sstatic.net/A2OiP0y8.png

The Worksheets.Comments property contains the old-style Notes — a yellow box, optional bold heading/name, no replies, and cannot be 'Resolved'.
The Worksheets.CommentsThreaded property contains the new-style Comment Threads, which support Replies and can be Resolved.
So, Worksheets(1).CommentsThreaded.Count will tell you how many Comment Threads there are, but you will need to loop through them to see how many have been Resolved.  For example:
Function ResolvedThreads(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim ct As CommentThreaded, rt As Long
    rt = 0
    
    For Each ct In ws.CommentsThreaded
        If ct.Resolved Then rt = rt + 1
    Next ct
    
    ResolvedThreads = rt
End Function

